# How to detect android front camera programmatically

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to check if the android phone has a front camera too? I'd tried to use some help form https://docs.google.com/View?id=dhtsnvs6_57d2hpqtgr but Camera camera = FrontFacingCamera.getFrontFacingCamera(); sometimes works sometimes not.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me how to check if the android phone has a front camera too?

There is no API for this, at least through Android 2.2. Sorry!

> I'd tried to use some help form https://docs.google.com/View?id=dhtsnvs6_57d2hpqtgr but Camera camera = FrontFacingCamera.getFrontFacingCamera(); sometimes works sometimes not.

That is for two specific models of phones, not for Android devices in general. With luck, the upcoming Gingerbread release will add built-in support for front-facing cameras.

In the meantime, you need to get the instructions (like the one you linked to) from each and every device manufacturer and attempt to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean hasFlash() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        try {
            if(camManager==null)
                camManager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(  CAMERA_SERVICE );
            String cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[1];
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = camManager.getCameraCharacteristics( cameraId );
            return cameraCharacteristics.get( CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```