# How to detect if there is front camera and if there is how to reach and use front camera?

Tags: android, camera

How to detect if there is a front camera and if there is how to reach and use front camera ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922042/how-to-detect-android-front-camera-programmatically (But with no answer at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to detect if there is a front camera and if there is how to reach and use front camera ?

There is no API for this, at least through Android 2.2. With luck, the upcoming Gingerbread release will add built-in support for front-facing cameras. Sorry!

Answer (score 19):

If you are using API level 9 (Android 2.3) or above, you can do the following to calculate the index of the (first) front-facing camera:

```
int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
    }
    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
```

you can then use the index for the `Camera.open` method, e.g.:

```
int index = getFrontCameraId();
if (index == -1) error();
Camera c = Camera.open(index);
```

To get the relevant camera.

Comment: checking for cameraid does not work on kindle fire. It has only one camera front mounted and it has id  == back_camera_id.

Answer (score 5):

Oak your code will not support sdk above 21 so i have added these lines to make it useable :)

```
    int getFrontCameraId(CameraManager cManager) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
        Camera.CameraInfo ci = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
            if (ci.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            for ( int j = 0;j<cManager.getCameraIdList().length; j++) {
                String[] cameraId = cManager.getCameraIdList();
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId[j]);
                int cOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) 
                    return j;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
```

**I have updated the code of Oak which now supports new camera2 library also.**

Answer (score 0):

Kalpit, I don't know how you managed to get the code working. I tried to edit your answer, but the full answer needs to be changed. Here's what I got.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi" )
int getFrontCameraId() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
        Camera.CameraInfo ci = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
            if (ci.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            CameraManager cManager = (CameraManager) getApplicationContext()
               .getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            String[] cameraId = cManager.getCameraIdList();
            for ( int j = 0;j<cameraId.length; j++) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId[j]);
                int cOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (cOrientation == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
                    return Integer.parseInt(cameraId[j]);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
```